# How to remove last special character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data

```
Name
Mohankim@gmail.com
Mohankim@gmail.com.
ramkim@gmail.com.
```

I want result set like

```
Name
Mohankim@gmail.com
ramkim@gmail.com
```

**My script** :

```
Select *,CASE WHEN Name = PATINDEX('%[.]%',Name) THEN LEFT(Name, LEN(Name) - 1) ELSE FQDN END T 
from mail
```

suggest me

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.  Are you filtering the results or removing the trailing period?

Comment: Do you mean "remove last character if it's special character"?

Comment: I think you want `CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%.',Name) > 0 …`.

Comment: yes @jarlh exactly

Comment: you should be cleansing your data on the way in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @VARI as VARCHAR(25)
SET @VARI='pradeep_sb@gmail.com.'
print @vari
select SUBSTRING(@VARI,LEN('pradeep_sb@gmail.com.'),1)


select
case
when '.'=SUBSTRING(@VARI,LEN('pradeep_sb@gmail.com.'),1)then SUBSTRING(@VARI,1,LEN(@vari)-1)else @VARI end as a
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the trailing period:

```
select (case when name like '%.' then left(name, len(name) - 1) else name end) as name
from mail;
```

If you want just the unique list of resulting names:

```
select distinct (case when name like '%.' then left(name, len(name) - 1) else name end) as name
from mail;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(Name)
AS
(
SELECT 'Mohankim@gmail.com@'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mohankim@gmail.com#' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mohankim@gmail.com$' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mohankim@gmail.com' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ramkim@gmail.com.'
)
SELECT Name,IIF(PATINDEX('%[. , @ # $]%',REVERSE(Name))=1 ,LEFT(Name,LEN(Name)-1),Name)
 AS ReFormatName 
FRom CTE
```

Result

```
Name                ReqFormatName
----------------------------------------
Mohankim@gmail.com@ Mohankim@gmail.com
Mohankim@gmail.com# Mohankim@gmail.com
Mohankim@gmail.com$ Mohankim@gmail.com
Mohankim@gmail.com  Mohankim@gmail.com
ramkim@gmail.com.   ramkim@gmail.com
```

Comment: What will happen with address "andy@commerzbank.de"?